# How to write a particular mathematical expression

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, mathtools

I am trying to write an equation which is:

[image]

Now wrote something like this:

```
$\Delta_w_{k} = p\Delta_w_{k-1} + \Alpha_p$
```

I  wrote it partly as I wanted to check whether I was doing the right thing or not. But It did not compile. Please can anyone tell me where the error is?

Comment: It's `\alpha`, not `\Alpha`; and multiplication is denoted by `\cdot` or, preferably, by nothing. The subscript symbol after `\Delta` is wrong, remove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Read the console output. Sometimes, it tells you useful stuff!!!***

In this case, it tells you that you have a 'double subscript'. If you correct that, it tells you you have another. If you correct that, it points out that `\Alpha` is not defined. Correcting that, it finally compiles:

[image: compiled]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\Delta_{w_{k}} = p\Delta_{w_{k-1}} + \alpha_p$

  Or, as CroCo says, you might want

  $\Delta w_{k} = p\cdot\Delta w_{k-1} + \alpha\cdot p\cdot\frac{\Delta E_k}{\Delta w_k}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess $w_{k}$ shouldn't be subscripted? Isn't it? Also the case for $p$. This is what I can tell from the picture the OP shows.

Comment: @CroCo Thanks. I wasn't sure because the code didn't seem to match the picture anyway. I've edited to cover both....